# jquery $.ajax() not working in application hosted server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on CI app...having little bit problem in jquery $.ajax.its working fine in localhost but in hosted server most of the time not working

```
<?php $this->load->helper('url'); ?>
var generate = '<?php echo site_url('pingenerator'); ?>';

function generate_pin(){
        alert(generate);//testing purpose  
        var package = $("#packagetype").val();
        var times = $("#noofpins").val();
    $.ajax({
        'url' : generate,
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : {'packagetype' : package,'noofpins' : times },
        'success' : function(data){
            var container = $('#pin_generator_msg'); 
                  alert('ajax complete');//testing purpose
                 container.html(data);
            }
    });
}
```

url works fine when copy peasting in add bar...
$.ajax is not calling at all

---

adding both scripts jquery-1.10.2.min.js and jquery.smartTab.min.js causing no problem for type GET AND POST without passing any data.

if i pass data for type GET calling the javascript file showing home page in display part. this script.js not added in problem causing context

calling link:
GET http://skylabsinc.in/pages/index.php/js/script.js

if i pass data for type POST calling,causing error

POST http://skylabsinc.in/pages/index.php/pingenerator [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 831ms]

Comment: did you check the console of browser for errors ?

Comment: did you call your function anywhere?

Comment: yes...i called in submit form

Comment: Did you check your Jquery library Url?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for your jquery.js, whether its included correctly.
2. Check for the jquery.js version. It may be a older version
3. Check in your Firebug's console mode and post the error.

What is the error you are getting? If you tell that it will be helpful.

Comment: i checked in browser console i got this- [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 831ms]....sometimes it works fine

Comment: 1 is ok..2 its jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js is the newer version so no problem with that. Check for your server side configurations.

Comment: Try including some other older versions of Jquery. And check whether have you included jquery.js (twice) in that page.

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js,jquery.smartTab.min.js these to i have added

Comment: var  transfer= 'getpinstotransfer';
    var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';

    function transfer_pins(){
        $.ajax({
            'url' : base_url + '/' + transfer,
            'type' : 'POST',
            'success' : function(data){
            var container = $('#showpins'); 
                if(data){
                    container.html(data);
                }
            }   
        });
    }                                                           Another part i am using same code concept... its working fine...

Comment: Ok, Then remove all the included scripts in that page one by one and check whether it is working. Because in that page you might have added a specific script and it may cause this error.

Comment: As you mentioned in one of your comment "But currently i obsereved that routing goes to exact location what i wanted but returning in returning is unwanted page(home)". If feel like there is a redirection happening in the ajax action page. It may be a session redirection. Put session_star() and check there. It's just a guess. Anyhow try it out.